# jQuery plugin defaults

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Is there a way to change the defaults within a plugin after they have been set. For example.

```
var defaults = {
 imageWidth : w,
 imageHeight : h
};
```

Later in the code I want to change the imageWidth value again.

Comment: Can you link to the plugin source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe, depends on the plugin. If it looks like this:

```
(function() {
    var defaults = { /* ... */ };
    // Rest of the plugin goes here.
})();
```

Then you're out of luck. However, quite a few plugins publish their defaults as:

```
$.fn.plugin.defaults
```

Where `plugin` is the plugin name. If the defaults are publicly accessible like that (or if you want to hack the plugin to make them public), then you can change the defaults whenever you want. Of course, the new defaults won't apply to existing instances.

---

If this your own plugin then I think your architecture is a bit off. The "full screen" versus "specified width and height" configuration should be an option for the plugin and leave the default as something sensible (where "sensible" is, as always, context dependent). Then you'd just say this:

```
$(x).plugin({ fullscreen: true }); // Full screen
// or
$(y).plugin({ w: 11, h: 23 });     // Specific dimensions
```

You could also use the `$.fn.plugin.defaults` trick to allow the *sensible* defaults to be changed as needed.

Comment: It's actually my plugin. I want to reset the default values later in the plugin. Basically there's an option to specify your own width or fullscreen. If it's fullscreen I have to get the browser width, but for some reason once I set the width, I can't then reset it later in the plugin.

Comment: @Ian: I've added some ideas about that.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, if fullscreen is an option and it defaults to false, and the height and width defaults to the images size in that case, then I need to check the option before I know if it's fullscreen and by then the widths have already been set, so I need to reset them again.

Comment: You'd probably have `fullscreen:true` as a default then or no default at all. Then get the width/height when you need them.

Comment: Thanks for your help, my architecture was off. Instead of trying to change the values I've checked what the options are before setting the defaults. I was trying to do it after, so setting up some conditional logic before and then assigning those to the defaults after gets around the whole issue.